# .scss file not found when deploy to heroku

Tags: mern

I am trying to deploy to heroku a MERN app that uses mdc-react component library. But i  get an error that a file cannot be found.But the file exists.

Running the build locally from nodejs server, app runs but overidded styles are not working. It works as expected if run from the client folder.

I suspect it has to do with folder structure or import path. Images below show project folder structure, error and code on nodejs server. How can i resolve this. Thanks in advance
[image: folder structure]
[image: Error From Heroku]
[image: server code]

```
    app.use(express.static('./client/build'))

    app.get('*', (req, res)=> {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
    })
```

I expect all styles should be imported

Comment: 11 months on I'm getting this, any luck?